# How to find missing/invisible messages in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

One of our users recently filled up his mailbox (3 GB of data) despite having practically nothing in his inbox or any of his e-mail folders.  He says he should have many things, but they simply don't display anymore.  I migrated him to O365 so he'd have more room to roam.  It also says 3 GB used, so everything copied over, but the same issue there.  He's got practically nothing in any of his folders.  Can't even begin to account for the 3 GB of space used with what shows up.  It must be all the vanished e-mail he's talking about, but we can't find it anywhere.  Is there a way to locate all e-mail including what is apparently invisible e-mail?

Comment: You may refer to the instructions in this link(https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-s-the-size-of-my-mailbox-c76c6ae0-d07f-45da-8d91-0936108895d3) to check the size for the mailbox and each subfolder in Outlook. This helps identify where the invisible items are. Besides, check in OWA and see if the items can be seen.

Comment: @YukiSun Mailbox and subfolders are all small when you look at them (just a few hundred MB total).  Yet, the mailbox total is well over 3 GB according to the user mailbox usage screen!